# Convince Arara to compile .tikz files

Tags: tikz-pgf, arara, tikzscale

I have recently learned about the package `tikzscale` and find it to be a great solution to many issues I was having. However, using it requires the file containing the tikz code to have the extension `.tikz`. Previously all my tikz files would be standalone so i could compile them independently to inspect the output, but with the tikz extension I can't figure out how to compile my standalone tikz pictures using arara directives like usual.

My `.tikz` files looks like this

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [orange] (0.1, 0.1) rectangle (0.2, 0.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have attempted to modify the araraconfig.yaml file to contain the following:

```
!config
filetypes:
  - extension: tex
  - extension: dtx
  - extension: ltx
  - extension: tikz
    pattern: ^(\\s)*%\\s+
```

but arara fails, saying `...no directives were found`. Is there a way to convince arara to treat a `.tikz` file as it would a `.tex` file, or do i need to add a whole new set of rules to my arara rules for the `.tikz` extension?

Comment: I think the pattern is wrong (don't escape the backslashes). Try `pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+` or the default pattern from the manual: `^\s*%\s+`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern is wrong. You don't have to escape backslashes.

[image]

Try instead: `pattern: ^\s*%\s+`.

araraconfig.yaml:

```
!config
filetypes:
  - extension: tex
  - extension: dtx
  - extension: ltx
  - extension: tikz
    pattern: ^\s*%\s+
```

Running `arara` succeds:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'test.tikz' (size: 205 bytes, last modified:
02/09/2019 21:57:14), please wait.

(LuaLaTeX) LuaLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS
(LuaLaTeX) LuaLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

Total: 2.31 seconds
```

Result (zoomed in a bit):

[image]

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I totally missed that warning

Comment: Well, [this](https://xkcd.com/1171/) applies here too